# how can i accept "null" word in my integer value? its like if i enter the word "null" the output would be empty. like, Enter your age: null, Your age:

Tags: c#

```
        int? age;
        Console.Write("\nInsert  age: ");
        age = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        if (age == null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Your age:" + age);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Your age: ");
        }
```

It works correctly if i put integer but every time i put the word "null" it always appears "exception unhandle". Anyone there who can help me out

```
The program output should be this:
 Insert Age:12
 Your age:12


 Insert Age:null
 Your age:
```

Comment: Store the result of `Console.ReadLine()` in a `string` variable and then determine if you should assign null or parse as an integer.

Comment: read your input to a string first, then check with `if(input=="null")`?

Comment: How should the program handle other input from the console? E.g. if `Insert  age:` is answered with (nothing) or `hello`?

Comment: thank you for all your responses it really helped me alot.

Answer (score 0):

> **You cannot store string values in int datatype.**
> Below code achieves your expected outcome. In string variable age - you can store both - age number in string format and null value.

```
        string age;
        Console.Write("\nInsert  age: ");
        age = Console.ReadLine();

        if (age.Equals("null"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Your age:"+"");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Your age:"+age);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Comment: i think this is the right answer thanks dude! God bless! Stay safe!

Comment: You can up vote and accept my answer if it helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

I would sugest to use a convert method which does not throw a exception like TryParse. This method returns a bool to check if the input string contained a valid integer:

```
bool validNumber = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out var age);
if (validNumber)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Your age: {age}");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Your age: ");
}
```

Comment: thanks! really appreciated this answer